# Tool to collect locations submitted by anonymous user

Tags: maps, forms, geo-location, openstreetmap, google-maps

I need something like google forms, but to collect Locations (longitude, lattitude) Unfortunately goolge forms doesn't support that.
Users should be able to drop a marker on a map and submit it like that. 
Ideally, I should be able to see those locations on a map as well.

Comment: So you're looking for a web app to self-host? And it must support both, OSM and GMaps (as you've applied both tags in addition to the `maps` tag)?

Comment: In the meantime I found a service called jotform, it lets you create custom forms and also has some location widgets. Its not perfect, but i can work with it: jotform.com

Comment: On SE sites, it's perfectly fine to [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) (also [see here](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question)) – but answers should be posted as answers (and give some more details on how the product fits etc.) Mind to write up an answer? And please also consider including the details I asked in my first comment with your question post so it gets clear what you're after. Someone might come up with an even better solution ;)